# How to use canvas and mouse event to move a circle?

Tags: javascript, canvas, mousemove

I need some help with a project for school if anyone is willing  this is the task we use canvas-javascript'When you start the game, a circle is generated in the center of the screen. We call that circle
main circle;
● The player controls the movement of the main circle by moving the mouse. The circle moves across the canvas
by following the mouse arrow. More precisely, it is necessary to move the center of the main circle to
the direction of the current cursor position on the canvas at a certain speed (for example, 20px / s);
● The game starts when the player moves the mouse (ie the main circle);

Comment: You say you want the circle to follow the movement of the circle, but what does that mean at a certain speed? circle follow the movement of the mouse then you can't restrict the speed of it. Also, you just want to custom a mouse or you want to make soemthing like a drawing tool. I am kind confused with your question.

Comment: the speed is not that important im builidng a game and this is the first step to generate a circle and use the mouse to move it

Comment: So you only want to build a circle that follow the mouse movement. Is that correct?

Comment: yes that is correct :-)

Comment: Just post an answer, check if it works

Answer (score 1):

Since you only want to make a circle that follow the mouse, so a combination of `mousemove` and `clientX`/`clientY` will be a good option.

```js
        let div = document.querySelector('#cursor')
        document.querySelector('canvas').onmousemove = function(event){
            //track mouse position and change for custom cursor
            div.style.left = event.clientX-5+'px'
            div.style.top = event.clientY-5+'px'
        };
```

```css
canvas{
    width: 50vw;
    height: 50vh;
    border: 2px solid red;
}
#cursor{
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background: red;
    position: absolute;
    top: 25%;
    left: 25%;
    border-radius:50%;
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
   <div id=cursor></div>
```

Comment: This was very helpful many thanks James

Comment: @Crash263, no problem. You could accept the answer if you think it is helpful:)